# Magento2 : How to get product id to my custom module

Tags: magento2, product, module, custom

I am new to magento2 and currently I'm building a custom module and i want to get the product `ID/SKU` from the catalog. 
I'm trying to call using a function located in the Block folder. please advise!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    echo $product->getId();
    echo $product->getName();
?>
```

**OR**

Add bellow code in your block file.

**for example** `app/code/AR/CustomModule/Block/CustomBlock.php`

```
<?php
namespace AR\CustomModule\Block;
class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {       
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {       
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {       
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }   

}
?>
```

Printing current product data in your template (custom.phtml) file

```
if ($currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct()) {
    echo $currentProduct->getName() . '<br />';
    echo $currentProduct->getSku() . '<br />';
    echo $currentProduct->getId() . '<br />';       
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Do you mind explaining about this registry?? is there a developer's guide on this area??

Comment: Is there any alternate method to get product id apart from registry?

Comment: `Registry` is deprecated. What is the best practice way to achieve this?

Comment: wow greate soluions, work for me thanks @abdul

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $productid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');                                       
     $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productid);
     echo $product;
?>
```

use this code for to get current product id

Comment: It's a good answer. You just need to check if you're on product detail page and then get ID from the request payload.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
echo $product->getId();
echo $product->getName();
?>
```

This works for me.

.

Comment: don't use object manager directly

Answer (score 0):

You could try `$product = $this->abstractProduct->getProduct();`

with `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $abstractProduct`

worked for me :)

Comment: its not working for product listing page

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
    echo $product->getId();
    echo $product->getName();
    echo $product->getSku();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$productid=22501;
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

```
 $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
 $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

 $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productid);
 
 $data = json_encode($product->getData());

 print_r($data);
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
<?php  
   $productId = 8;
   $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $currentproduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
   echo $currentproduct->getName(); 
?>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I think i have phrased my question wrongly. My current modules is just an add on information for the product, what i really meant is that how do i get the ID of the current page product? example, in "localhost/test/product-A.html" how can i retrieve the id for this particular product

Comment: i get  Class 'Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager not found

Comment: i m trying to get in my custom  Model as :  $productId = 1;
  $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $currentproduct = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Queue')->load($productId);  echo '<pre>';print_r($currentproduct->getEntityId());die;   i get call to dispatch() on null ..pls help

Comment: How to dynamically get the  $productId = 8;