# Magento2 the custom block class had extended abstract product but to get product that was null,please help me

Tags: magento2

the code of My custom module block class

```
<?php
namespace  Customization\Design\Block;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;

class  Design extends AbstractProduct {

    protected $_hash;

    protected $_cofig;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
             array $data = []
    ){

        parent::__construct(
                $context,
                $data
        );
    }
}
```

The phtml file  code

```
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); var_dump($_product);?>

print：NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

For ex. You have custom block

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Index/Index.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
{   

}
```

Then simple you can get AbstractProduct methods by this way in block or phtml file

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/index/index.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getAddToCompareUrl(); // AbstractProduct Method ?>
```

Comment: I'm want to get  product  $this->getProduct() ,not " $this->getAddToCompareUrl()"

Comment: @LINGOGLE $this->getProduct() is used to Retrieve currently viewed product object you can not get data directly from this method. Please refer AbstractProduct block for more details.

Comment: so,in your opinion ,what I need to do can get the current product?

Comment: @LINGOGLE refer this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/109622/35758