# Get product detail at custom phtml in catalog view layout

Tags: magento2, product, layout

I added new block to load my custom phtml inside catalog view,the problem is i need to load the current product model at my phtml, but i don't know how to do it.

**app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.social">
        <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Custom" name="custom.product.view" template="Namespace_Module::custom.phtml"> </block>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Check here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109622/magento2-how-to-get-product-id-to-my-custom-module/109635#109635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two way you can current product object at your custom class

### First

using registry variable, In product details at every block section, you get forestry variable `current_product` .

Inject the  registry class on you class **__construct()** function

```
 /**
 * Core registry
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $_coreRegistry;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry    
    ...
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
}

/**
 * Retrieve current product object
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
 */
public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
}
```

### Second

second, once extends `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View`  which @keyur [already explained](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/209017/4564)

Answer (score 1):

Adding from the [@Amit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4564/amit-bera) answer, If you are creating a new block (As you mentioned in question `Namespace\Module\Block\Custom`) then just extend your block class with `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View`. Now you can access `$product` object in `phtml` file like `$block->getProduct()`

Comment: Ha ha , that i will going to add..

Comment: Yes, I think its simplest answer just extend the class and you have all properties of `$product` object :)  @AmitBera

Comment: Ya, it is depends on devloper call, If his/her class already extends  another then they must use  registry.other wise your solution is super

Comment: Yes, I agree with you `registry` is the best option to get `$product` object anywhere , +1 for your efforts :) @AmitBera